# How to replace an instance with another instance via pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv, stl

I'm doing online destructive clustering (clusters replace clustered objects) on a list of class instances (stl::list).

### Background

My list of current percepUnits is: `stl::list<percepUnit> units;` and for each iteration I get a new list of input percepUnits `stl::list<percepUnit> scratch;` that need to be clustered with the units.

I want to maintain a fixed number of percepUnits (so units.size() is constant), so for each new scratch percepUnit I need to merge it with the nearest percepUnit in units. Following is a code snippet that builds a list (`dists`) of structures (`percepUnitDist`) that contain pointers to each pair of items in scratch and units `percepDist.scratchUnit = &(*scratchUnit);` and `percepDist.unit = &(*unit);` and their distance. Additionally, for each item in scratch I keep track of which item in units has the least distance `minDists`.

```
// For every scratch percepUnit:
for (scratchUnit = scratch.begin(); scratchUnit != scratch.end(); scratchUnit++) { 
    float minDist=2025.1172; // This is the max possible distance in unnormalized CIELuv, and much larger than the normalized dist.
    // For every percepUnit:
    for (unit = units.begin(); unit != units.end(); unit++) { 

        // compare pairs
        float dist = featureDist(*scratchUnit, *unit, FGBG);
        //cout << "distance: " << dist << endl;

        // Put pairs in a structure that caches their distances
        percepUnitDist percepDist;
        percepDist.scratchUnit = &(*scratchUnit); // address of where scratchUnit points to.
        percepDist.unit = &(*unit);
        percepDist.dist = dist;

        // Figure out the percepUnit that is closest to this scratchUnit.
        if (dist < minDist)
            minDist = dist;

        dists.push_back(percepDist); // append dist struct
    }
    minDists.push_back(minDist); // append the min distance to the nearest percepUnit for this particular scratchUnit.
}
```

So now I just need to loop through the `percepUnitDist` items in `dists` and match the distances with the minimum distances to figure out which percepUnit in scratch should be merged with which percepUnit in units. The merging process `mergePerceps()` creates a new percepUnit which is a weighted average of the "parent" percepUnits in scratch and units.

### Question

I want to replace the instance in the units list with the new percepUnit constructed by mergePerceps(), but I would like to do so in the context of looping through the percepUnitDists. This is my current code:

```
// Loop through dists and merge all the closest pairs.
// Loop through all dists
for (distIter = dists.begin(); distIter != dists.end(); distIter++) {
    // Loop through all minDists for each scratchUnit.
    for (minDistsIter = minDists.begin(); minDistsIter != minDists.end(); minDistsIter++) {
        // if this is the closest cluster, and the closest cluster has not already been merged, and the scratch has not already been merged.
        if (*minDistsIter == distIter->dist and not distIter->scratchUnit->remove) {

            percepUnit newUnit;
            mergePerceps(*(distIter->scratchUnit), *(distIter->unit), newUnit, FGBG);
            *(distIter->unit) = newUnit; // replace the cluster with the new merged version.

            distIter->scratchUnit->remove = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that I could replace the instance in units via the percepUnitDist pointer with the new percepUnit instance using `*(distIter->unit) = newUnit;`, but that does not seem to be working as I'm seeing a memory leak, implying the instances in the units are not getting replaced.

How do I delete the percepUnit in the units list and replace it with a new percepUnit instance such that the new unit is located in the same location?

### EDIT1

[Here](http://www.ekran.org/tmp/percepUnit.zip) is the percepUnit class. Note the cv::Mat members. Following is the mergePerceps() function and the mergeImages() function on which it depends:

```
// Function to construct an accumulation.
void clustering::mergeImages(Mat &scratch, Mat &unit, cv::Mat &merged, const string maskOrImage, const string FGBG, const float scratchWeight, const float unitWeight) {

    int width, height, type=CV_8UC3;
    Mat scratchImagePad, unitImagePad, scratchImage, unitImage;

    // use the resolution and aspect of the largest of the pair.
    if (unit.cols > scratch.cols)
        width = unit.cols;
    else
        width = scratch.cols;

    if (unit.rows > scratch.rows)
        height = unit.rows;
    else
        height = scratch.rows;

    if (maskOrImage == "mask") 
        type = CV_8UC1; // single channel mask
    else if (maskOrImage == "image")
        type = CV_8UC3; // three channel image
    else
        cout << "maskOrImage is not 'mask' or 'image'\n";

    merged = Mat(height, width, type, Scalar::all(0));
    scratchImagePad = Mat(height, width, type, Scalar::all(0));
    unitImagePad = Mat(height, width, type, Scalar::all(0));

    // weight images before summation.
    // because these pass by reference, they mess up the images in memory!
    scratch *= scratchWeight;
    unit *= unitWeight;

    // copy images into padded images.
    scratch.copyTo(scratchImagePad(Rect((scratchImagePad.cols-scratch.cols)/2,
                                             (scratchImagePad.rows-scratch.rows)/2,
                                              scratch.cols,
                                              scratch.rows)));

    unit.copyTo(unitImagePad(Rect((unitImagePad.cols-unit.cols)/2,
                                       (unitImagePad.rows-unit.rows)/2,
                                        unit.cols,
                                        unit.rows)));

    merged = scratchImagePad+unitImagePad;
}

// Merge two perceps and return a new percept to replace them.
void clustering::mergePerceps(percepUnit scratch, percepUnit unit, percepUnit &mergedUnit, const string FGBG) {

    Mat accumulation;
    Mat accumulationMask;
    Mat meanColour;
    int x, y, w, h, area;
    float l,u,v;
    int numMerges=0;
    std::vector<float> featuresVar; // Normalized, Sum, Variance.
    //float featuresVarMin, featuresVarMax; // min and max variance accross all features.
    float scratchWeight, unitWeight;

    if (FGBG == "FG") {
        // foreground percepts don't get merged as much.
        scratchWeight = 0.65;
        unitWeight = 1-scratchWeight;
    } else {
        scratchWeight = 0.85;
        unitWeight = 1-scratchWeight;
    }

    // Images TODO remove the meanColour if needbe.
    mergeImages(scratch.image, unit.image, accumulation, "image", FGBG, scratchWeight, unitWeight);
    mergeImages(scratch.mask, unit.mask, accumulationMask, "mask", FGBG, scratchWeight, unitWeight);
    mergeImages(scratch.meanColour, unit.meanColour, meanColour, "image", "FG", scratchWeight, unitWeight); // merge images 


    // Position and size.
    x = (scratch.x1*scratchWeight) + (unit.x1*unitWeight);
    y = (scratch.y1*scratchWeight) + (unit.y1*unitWeight);
    w = (scratch.w*scratchWeight) + (unit.w*unitWeight);
    h = (scratch.h*scratchWeight) + (unit.h*unitWeight);

    // area
    area = (scratch.area*scratchWeight) + (unit.area*unitWeight);

    // colour
    l = (scratch.l*scratchWeight) + (unit.l*unitWeight);
    u = (scratch.u*scratchWeight) + (unit.u*unitWeight);
    v = (scratch.v*scratchWeight) + (unit.v*unitWeight);

    // Number of merges
    if (scratch.numMerges < 1 and unit.numMerges < 1) { // both units are patches
        numMerges = 1;
    } else if (scratch.numMerges < 1 and unit.numMerges >= 1) { // unit A is a patch, B a percept
        numMerges = unit.numMerges + 1;
    } else if (scratch.numMerges >= 1 and unit.numMerges < 1) { // unit A is a percept, B a patch.
        numMerges = scratch.numMerges + 1;
        cout << "merged scratch??" <<endl;
        // TODO this may be an impossible case.
    } else { // both units are percepts
        numMerges = scratch.numMerges + unit.numMerges;
        cout << "Merging two already merged Percepts" <<endl;
        // TODO this may be an impossible case.
    }

    // Create unit.
    mergedUnit = percepUnit(accumulation, accumulationMask, x, y, w, h, area); // time is the earliest value in times?
    mergedUnit.l = l; // members not in the constrcutor.
    mergedUnit.u = u;
    mergedUnit.v = v;
    mergedUnit.numMerges = numMerges;
    mergedUnit.meanColour = meanColour;
    mergedUnit.pActivated = unit.pActivated; // new clusters retain parent's history of activation.
    mergedUnit.scratch = false;
    mergedUnit.habituation = unit.habituation; // we inherent the habituation of the cluster we merged with.
}
```

### EDIT2

Changing the copy and assignment operators had performance side-effects and did not seem to resolve the problem. So I've added a custom function to do the replacement, which just like the copy operator makes copies of each member and make's sure those copies are deep. The problem is that I still end up with a leak.

So I've changed this line: `*(distIter->unit) = newUnit;`

to this: `(*(distIter->unit)).clone(newUnit)`

Where the clone method is as follows:

```
// Deep Copy of members
void percepUnit::clone(const percepUnit &source) {
    // Deep copy of Mats
    this->image = source.image.clone();
    this->mask = source.mask.clone();
    this->alphaImage = source.alphaImage.clone();
    this->meanColour = source.meanColour.clone();

    // shallow copies of everything else    
    this->alpha = source.alpha;
    this->fadingIn = source.fadingIn;
    this->fadingHold = source.fadingHold;
    this->fadingOut = source.fadingOut;
    this->l = source.l;
    this->u = source.u;
    this->v = source.v;
    this->x1 = source.x1;
    this->y1 = source.y1;
    this->w = source.w;
    this->h = source.h;
    this->x2 = source.x2;
    this->y2 = source.y2;
    this->cx = source.cx;
    this->cy = source.cy;
    this->numMerges = source.numMerges;
    this->id = source.id;
    this->area = source.area;
    this->features = source.features;
    this->featuresNorm = source.featuresNorm;
    this->remove = source.remove;
    this->fgKnockout = source.fgKnockout;
    this->colourCalculated = source.colourCalculated;
    this->normalized = source.normalized;
    this->activation = source.activation;
    this->activated = source.activated;
    this->pActivated = source.pActivated;
    this->habituation = source.habituation;
    this->scratch = source.scratch;
    this->FGBG = source.FGBG;
}
```

And yet, I still see a memory increase. The increase does not happen if I comment out that single replacement line. So I'm still stuck.

### EDIT3

I can prevent memory from increasing if I disable the cv::Mat cloning code in the function above:

```
// Deep Copy of members
void percepUnit::clone(const percepUnit &source) {
    /* try releasing Mats first?
    // No effect on memory increase, but the refCount is decremented.
    this->image.release();
    this->mask.release();
    this->alphaImage.release();
    this->meanColour.release();*/

    /* Deep copy of Mats
    this->image = source.image.clone();
    this->mask = source.mask.clone();
    this->alphaImage = source.alphaImage.clone();
    this->meanColour = source.meanColour.clone();*/

    // shallow copies of everything else    
    this->alpha = source.alpha;
    this->fadingIn = source.fadingIn;
    this->fadingHold = source.fadingHold;
    this->fadingOut = source.fadingOut;
    this->l = source.l;
    this->u = source.u;
    this->v = source.v;
    this->x1 = source.x1;
    this->y1 = source.y1;
    this->w = source.w;
    this->h = source.h;
    this->x2 = source.x2;
    this->y2 = source.y2;
    this->cx = source.cx;
    this->cy = source.cy;
    this->numMerges = source.numMerges;
    this->id = source.id;
    this->area = source.area;
    this->features = source.features;
    this->featuresNorm = source.featuresNorm;
    this->remove = source.remove;
    this->fgKnockout = source.fgKnockout;
    this->colourCalculated = source.colourCalculated;
    this->normalized = source.normalized;
    this->activation = source.activation;
    this->activated = source.activated;
    this->pActivated = source.pActivated;
    this->habituation = source.habituation;
    this->scratch = source.scratch;
    this->FGBG = source.FGBG;
}
```

### <s>EDIT4</s>

While I still can't explain this issue, I did notice another hint. I realized that this leak can also be stopped if I don't normalize those features I use to cluster via featureDist() (but continue to clone cv::Mats). The really odd thing is that I rewrote that code entirely and still the problem persists.

Here is the featureDist function:

```
float clustering::featureDist(percepUnit unitA, percepUnit unitB, const string FGBG) {
    float distance=0;

    if (FGBG == "BG") {
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<unitA.featuresNorm.rows; i++) { 
            distance += pow(abs(unitA.featuresNorm.at<float>(i) - unitB.featuresNorm.at<float>(i)),0.5);
            //cout << "unitA.featuresNorm[" << i << "]: " << unitA.featuresNorm[i] << endl;
            //cout << "unitB.featuresNorm[" << i << "]: " << unitB.featuresNorm[i] << endl;
        }
    // for FG, don't use normalized colour features.
    // TODO To include the area use i=4
    } else if (FGBG == "FG") { 
        for (unsigned int i=4; i<unitA.features.rows; i++) { 
            distance += pow(abs(unitA.features.at<float>(i) - unitB.features.at<float>(i)),0.5);
        }
    } else {
        cout << "FGBG argument was not FG or BG, returning 0." <<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    return pow(distance,2);
}
```

Features used to be a vector of floats, and thus the normalization code was as follows:

```
void clustering::normalize(list<percepUnit> &scratch, list<percepUnit> &units) {

    list<percepUnit>::iterator unit;
    list<percepUnit*>::iterator unitPtr;
    vector<float> min,max;
    list<percepUnit*> masterList; // list of pointers.

    // generate pointers
    for (unit = scratch.begin(); unit != scratch.end(); unit++)
        masterList.push_back(&(*unit)); // add pointer to where unit points to.
    for (unit = units.begin(); unit != units.end(); unit++)
        masterList.push_back(&(*unit)); // add pointer to where unit points to.

    int numFeatures = masterList.front()->features.size(); // all percepts have the same number of features.
    min.resize(numFeatures); // allocate for the number of features we have.
    max.resize(numFeatures);

    // Loop through all units to get feature values
    for (int i=0; i<numFeatures; i++) { 

        min[i] = masterList.front()->features[i]; // starting point.
        max[i] = min[i];

        // calculate min and max for each feature.
        for (unitPtr = masterList.begin(); unitPtr != masterList.end(); unitPtr++) {

            if ((*unitPtr)->features[i] < min[i]) 
                min[i] = (*unitPtr)->features[i];
            if ((*unitPtr)->features[i] > max[i])
                max[i] = (*unitPtr)->features[i];
        }
    }

    // Normalize features according to min/max.
    for (int i=0; i<numFeatures; i++) { 
        for (unitPtr = masterList.begin(); unitPtr != masterList.end(); unitPtr++) {
            (*unitPtr)->featuresNorm[i] = ((*unitPtr)->features[i]-min[i]) / (max[i]-min[i]);
            (*unitPtr)->normalized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the features type to a cv::Mat so I could use the opencv normalization function, so I rewrote the normalization function as follows:

```
void clustering::normalize(list<percepUnit> &scratch, list<percepUnit> &units) {

    Mat featureMat = Mat(1,units.size()+scratch.size(), CV_32FC1, Scalar(0));
    list<percepUnit>::iterator unit;

    // For each feature
    for (int i=0; i< units.begin()->features.rows; i++) {

        // for each unit in units
        int j=0;
        float value;
        for (unit = units.begin(); unit != units.end(); unit++) {
            // Populate featureMat j is the unit index, i is the feature index.
            value = unit->features.at<float>(i);
            featureMat.at<float>(j) = value;
            j++;
        }
        // for each unit in scratch
        for (unit = scratch.begin(); unit != scratch.end(); unit++) {
            // Populate featureMat j is the unit index, i is the feature index.
            value = unit->features.at<float>(i);
            featureMat.at<float>(j) = value;
            j++;
        }

        // Normalize this featureMat in place
        cv::normalize(featureMat, featureMat, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX);

        // set normalized values in percepUnits from featureMat
        // for each unit in units
        j=0;
        for (unit = units.begin(); unit != units.end(); unit++) {
            // Populate percepUnit featuresNorm, j is the unit index, i is the feature index.
            value = featureMat.at<float>(j);
            unit->featuresNorm.at<float>(i) = value;
            j++;
        }
        // for each unit in scratch
        for (unit = scratch.begin(); unit != scratch.end(); unit++) {
            // Populate percepUnit featuresNorm, j is the unit index, i is the feature index.
            value = featureMat.at<float>(j);
            unit->featuresNorm.at<float>(i) = value;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand what the interaction between mergePercepts and normalization, especially since normalization is an entirely rewritten function.

### Update

**Massif and my /proc memory reporting don't agree. Massif says there is no effect of normalization on memory usage, only commenting out the percepUnit::clone() operation bypasses the leak.**

[Here](http://www.ekran.org/tmp/segmentationClustering_normalizeCluster.zip) is all the code, in case the interaction is somewhere else I am missing.

[Here](http://www.ekran.org/tmp/segmentationClustering_noGPU_leak.zip) is another version of the same code with the dependence on OpenCV GPU removed, to facilitate testing...

Comment: If `percepUnit` has an appropriate copy assignment operator, this code should work as written. The problem likely lies in the code you haven't shown - perhaps in the aforementioned assignment operator, or in `mergePerceps`. You say you have a memory leak - but the code you show doesn't allocate nor deallocate any memory. Look at the code that does.

Comment: I feel like I just got ran over by a pointer-truck. I concur with Igor. If you're relying on default-assignment of objects with dynamic allocation that don't practice RAII and the RO3, that would explain the problem you're seeing. Things like `distIter->scratchUnit->remove = true` are indicators that the RAII mantra "pointers should not own resources" is being circumvented.

Comment: Thanks. I'll include the percepUnit class and mergePerceps method above, sorry for the mess, many functions can be ignored. Since the code above looks right you to both, then I think the likely issue would be the cv::Mats (which are opencv smart pointers to images) that in normal assignment are shallow copied. I am just using the default assignment/copy operator now and I have no idea how to write a custom one that would automatically run the clone() method on Mats. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I tried using custom copy and assignment operators, but I still saw a memory increase. See EDIT2 above, where I took the guts of the custom copy operator and put it in its own method. My understanding is that the items in the original instance should just get replaced with new values, so I don't see how memory is increasing. Could something be interfering with the internal cv::Mat ref counting mechanism?

Comment: What is `this->image`? If it's a raw pointer to some heap-allocated object, then your `clone` implementation leaks whatever object it pointed to previously.

Comment: this->image is a cv::Mat (a refcounted smart pointer). It has its own release() method, but running release() on image, mask, alphaImage and meanColour (all cv::Mats) makes no apparent difference to the memory increase.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, see EDIT3 above. I'll also try cross-posting on opencv... Maybe there is some cv::Mat trickiness here. cv::Mat reference: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please see additional information above, and I've posted the test code.

Comment: @WhozCraig Please see additional information above (EDIT4). I'm really at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was recommended by Nghia (on the opencv forum) that I try and make the percepts a constant size. Sure enough, *if I fix the dimensions and type of the cv::Mat members of percepUnit, then the leak disappears*.

So it seems to me this is a bug in OpenCV that effects calling clone() and copyTo() on Mats of different sizes that are class members. So far unable to reproduce in a simple program. The leak does seem small enough that it may be the headers leaking, rather than the underlying image data.