# Fastest way to apply alpha channel to image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, optimization

I'm currently using the following function to apply my alpha channels (stored as separate GRAY cv::Mats), to images:

```
void percepUnit::applyAlpha() {

    int x,y,w,h;
    /*vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    if (image.rows == mask.rows and image.cols == mask.cols) {
        cv::split(image,channels); // break image into channels
        channels.push_back(mask); // append alpha channel

        cv::merge(channels,alphaImage); // combine channels
    }*/

    // Avoid merge
    cv::Mat src[] = {this->image, this->mask};
    int from_to[] = {0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3};
    this->alphaImage = Mat(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC4);
    cv::mixChannels(src, 2, &(this->alphaImage), 1, from_to, 4); // &(*alphaImage)?
}
```

I've had to increase the resolution of the cv::Mats to 1280x720 (due to: [How to replace an instance with another instance via pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772065/how-to-replace-an-instance-with-another-instance-via-pointer/22723888#22723888)) and now this function is running quite slowly, using up almost 50% of what is already a heavy meanshift segmentation application.

Any suggestions on how to apply these alpha channels faster? I'm running OpenCV with GPU, if you have any GPU based solutions.)

Comment: Actually, since I'm running this code on thousands of class instances, it seems like a great candidate for parallelism. My machine has 4 CPU cores, and the GPU has 2304 CUDA cores...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing split / merge on the GPU:

```
void percepUnit::applyAlpha() {

    cv::gpu::GpuMat tmpImage, tmpMask, tmpAlphaImage;
    std::vector<cv::gpu::GpuMat> channels;

    tmpImage.upload(this->image);
    tmpMask.upload(this->mask);

    cv::gpu::split(tmpImage,channels); // break image into channels
    channels.push_back(tmpMask); // append alpha channel
    cv::gpu::merge(channels,tmpAlphaImage); // combine channels

    tmpAlphaImage.download(this->alphaImage);

    tmpAlphaImage.release();
    tmpImage.release();
    tmpMask.release();

    channels[0].release();
    channels[1].release();
    channels[2].release();
}
```

Comment: Doing same thing as mentioned here but getting opencv exception at " cv::gpu::merge". How can I catch the exceptions? Should I make certain that the input is valid?

Comment: I would check that the number of channels are correct (1ch for alpha, 3 channel for image) and pixel dimensions match before running this function. Note that in my final program I was rendering in OpenGL and did the alpha application in a shader.